# Ізраїльська спецслужба: Моссад чи Мосад?

Tags: transliteration

`Моссад` вказується у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4) та книзі ["Моссад. Найвидатніші операції ізраїльської розвідки"](https://nashformat.ua/products/mossad.-najvydatnishi-operatsii-izrailskoi-rozvidky-709483).

Хоча в тій же вікіпедії вказується транслітерація `га-Мосад ле-модіін ве-лє-тафкідім меюхадім`, а, отже, `Мосад`.

На написанні `Мосад` наполягає також знайомий ізраїльтянин.

Як правильно?

Comment: Мені здається, що правильно з однією *с*.

Comment: Цікаво, що в більшості мов (зокрема й в англійській) два «с». Дізнатися б, чому так сталося… (Але все-таки не в усіх, наприклад іспанська й польська мають одне «с».)

Comment: Це велика загадка, звідки в англійському написанні взялася подвійна «c», в івритському слові [מוֹסָד](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/מוסד) (mosád) «установа, відомство» приголосна не подвоєна. В біблійній гебрейській, як і взагалі в більшості семітських мов, подвоєння приголосної (ґемінація) було дуже важливе й могло розрізняти слова, напр. מִלָּה millå̄ «слово» – מִילָה mīlå̄ «обрізання», та в сучасному івриті подвоєння зникло, ці 2 слова зараз звучать однаково, «міла́», проте воно все одно й досі позначається отою крапкою в букві, принаймні в словниках, так от у слові «мосад» крапки нема...

Answer (score 1):

Щодо подвоєння в запозичених, то я виступаю за те, щоб їх послідовно прибирати, незалежно від того, звучить подвоєння в мові-оригіналі [як в італійській], чи не звучить [як в англійській]. Роблю поки тільки один виняток: на стику префікса і кореня, тобто *ірраціональний* чи *Мак-Кабан*.

П.с. Була б моя воля, я б і в українських питомих подвоєння залишив тільки там, де воно виконує змістову навантагу, тобто для розрізнення сенсу слів, а ля *виконаний* і *виконанний*, і на стику префікса і кореня, а ля *беззубий*. Тобто життя чи знання я б теж писав як *житя* і *знаня* [так колись, до речі, і писали]